# How to fetch JSONArray values

Tags: android, json, parsing

In my program, I am able to fetch all my text. But In my JSOn  in a JSON Array there is another JSONArray which have image url. I am getting all my URL in JSON Array when I am using

```
JSONArray attachments = post.getJSONArray("itemimage");
```

but when loop is finished, I am getting nothing in my response. How can I replace my ImageView with URLs which is store in attatchment. My Code is here

```
private void parseResult(String result) {
    try {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("items");
        GridItem item;
        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
            String title = post.optString("itemname");
            item = new GridItem();
            item.setTitle(title);
            JSONArray attachments = post.getJSONArray("itemimage");
            if (null != attachments && attachments.length() > 0) {
                JSONObject attachment = attachments.getJSONObject(0);
                if (attachment != null)
                    item.setImage(attachment.getString(""));
                }
                mGridData.add(item);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post you logcat.

Comment: show `itemimage` JSONArray String which getting from server

Comment: HI @ρяσѕρєяK I am getting all my item image url  but after completing loop , thing is displaying

Comment: In this line    JSONObject attachment = attachments.getJSONObject(0); 

I am getting nothing.

Comment: @andorid_softy: probably `item.setImage(attachment.getString(""));` line causing issue instead of `""` use key name

Comment: actually in my JSON. itemimage Node doesn't have any object sign like { }
. after [ ] this my item url is mentioned like 0 : "my url"

Comment: what URL you are getting?.. and what setImage is doing..?

Comment: can you post your json

Comment: https://www.pujashoppe.com/anroid/product/index/category/puja-kits/

Comment: in this json there is a lst JSONArray Node named as itemimage.. and when you explore this node you will able to see 0 : image url

Comment: how you are setting the image in image view? are you able to get the URL of image from Json..??

Comment: Can you share your json response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um,i am 2 mins late post it out...cuz writing the demo for u.

The parse method you need is below,and you can use framework like Universal Image Loader  to load the url to your imageView.

```
    private String parseaaa(String jsonString) {

    String imgUrl = "";
    try {

        JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray mArray = mJsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
        for (int i = 0; i < mArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject object=mArray.getJSONObject(i);
            imgUrl+=object.getString("itemimage")+"\n";
            Log.i(TAG, imgUrl);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

  return imgUrl;
}
```

[image]

BTW,just use `JSONArray` to load things between `[]` and `JSONObject` to load the obj... It's  easy to do.

Comment: Thnxx bro... Actually I am new in JSON field so I was confused to how to get value from JSON Array.. thnx @NilDroid.. very muchh

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your `JSON` you should get **JSONException** at

```
JSONObject attachment = attachments.getJSONObject(0);
```

because your are creating *object* which is not present there, So I would suggest to simply extract `String` from your `JSONArray` and do your `setImage` stuff..

```
if (null != attachments && attachments.length() > 0) {
      String image= (String) attachments.get(0);
        //--- set your image here--//
}
```

Comment: Hi mohit.. Thnxxx bro.. you are life saver.. Thnxx for your quick response but I ma getting only one image ... rst two images are not appearing on Grid

Comment: hi i got everything.. thnxx bro